# Can anyone debug this bash script fro creating mysql db and user?

Tags: mysql, bash

Can anyone please tell me why I get this error after i run the command ?

```
root@server1:/home# ./dbcreate.sh db_team1 team1 team1password
ERROR 1133 (42000) at line 1: Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

This is the script I'm using.

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL=`which mysql`
ROOTPASSWD=mypassword

Q1="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $1;"
Q2="SET PASSWORD FOR '$2'@'localhost'= PASSWORD('$3');"
Q3="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $1.* TO '$2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$3';"
Q4="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}"

# Usage: $0 dbname dbuser dbpass"

$MYSQL -u root -p$ROOTPASSWD -e "$SQL"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` mod enabled so `GRANT` cannot create a new user (also, creating users via `GRANT` may not work in 5.5 and 5.6). For more see here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user

Answer (score 0):

Add user creation statement before attempting to associate the user to database

```
CREATE USER your_username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'your_user_password';
```

This should resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end instead:

echo "$SQL" | mysql -u root -p